# Angular 2 DomSanitizer: Cannot trust both HTML and CSS without also allowing JavaScript

Tags: angular, xss

I have user input that needs to be saved to the backend and rendered to other users as HTML. It needs to support links and CSS styling, but strip out JavaScript to avoid XSS attacks.

Consider a test input value of `test = "<span style='color: red;'><strong>Test</strong></span><img src='#' onerror='alert(1)' hidden><script>alert(2)</script>"`. If I use bypassSecurityTrustHtml from the DomSanitizer, it leaves everything in, including the unsafe JavaScript:

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(test)
// returns "<span style='color: red;'><strong>Test</strong></span><img src='#' onerror='alert(1)' hidden><script>alert(2)</script>"
```

However, if I use the sanitize method, it takes out the JavaScript but also removes the CSS:

```
this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, test);
// returns "<span><strong>Test</strong></span><img src="#" hidden="">alert(2)"
```

Is there anyway for me to use the DomSanitizer to keep HTML and CSS but remove JavaScript? Or will I need to use another library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Style attrs aren't safe, so if you don't trust your users 110%, don't allow them. Your app is only as safe as it's weakest link. It's probably why angular strips them too. If you must get around this, you need another solution.

There are many ways to do xss with styles but consider something as simple as:

```
<a href="https://malicious.site" style="position:absolute;z-index:9999;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;opacity:0">You can't see me</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. We do need to allow CSS, but only a strict set of styles (mainly color, italics, etc.). So I will probably have to find a library and/or write some code to strip out all JavaScript and allow a whitelist of CSS styles.