# Angular: safely embed markup preserving style attributes

Tags: html, angular, xss

I need to render an HTML markup preserving styles.

```
<div style="text-align: center">Some text</div>
```

And here how I render it:

```
<span [innerHTML]="content"></span>
```

But `innerHTML` removes style attributes. There are dozens and dozens questions on the internet and the only solution provided makes use of `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml`. But there are XSS security risks and this is not an option for me.

On the other hand I'm considering CSS as pretty safe, except [couple of tags](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Preventing_XSS_Attacks_through_CSS_Whitelisting) that could be whitelisted.

So there is an approach to render HTML markup, preserving CSS attributes but XSS safe?

Comment: Whatever utilizes `url(...)` in CSS might cause a risk and is therefore stripped out as long it isn't sanitized

Comment: Don't know the amount of inline styles but what about having those styles included in the global styles.(s)css file?

Comment: @Bernhard yes, there are a list of potentially vulnerable CSS and the one with `url` is among them, but my idea is that maybe we can mark as vulnerable just those specific CSS and pass through a harmless CSS like `text-align`. The HTML markup comes from wysiwyg editor and I have no control over it, otherwise I would need to invent my own editor which seems like a waste of time. I'm wondering whether there is a XSS safe solution before inventing a wheel :) Because I'm not the only one who has the problem depending on the amount of questions on the internet.

Comment: That requires to really know every vulnerable variation of malicious css. I think this answer covers it really well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49241760/1165289